# What is "this" in Meteor's "Template.myTemplate.rendered" callback?

Tags: meteor

According to the docs.meteor, in the body of the "Template.myTemplate.rendered" callback, "this" is a template instance object.

However, when I insert a "debugger" line in the callback and use the browser dev tools to check, the value of "this" is "window".  Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using the Leaderboard example - here's the handlebars template:

---

```
<template name="leaderboard">

    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}

  {{#if selected_name}}
  <div class="details">
    <div class="name">{{selected_name}}</div>
    <input type="button" class="inc" value="Give 5 points" />
    <input type="button" class="fastclick inc" value="Give 5 points - fast" />
  </div>
  {{/if}}

  {{#unless selected_name}}
  <div class="none">Click a player to select</div>
  {{/unless}}
</template>

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}} fastclick">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the "Template.leaderboard.rendered" callback:

---

```
  Template.leaderboard.rendered = function (){
    Meteor.defer(function() {
debugger;
      new FastClick(document.body);
      console.log("Template.leaderboard.rendered: " + JSON.stringify(this));
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code? ... both your handlebars template, and your `rendered` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `this` is inside the `Meteor.defer` callback, which means that the context of `this` has changed. Try caching `this` in a variable, and then outputting that variable in `console.log()`. For example:

```
Template.leaderboard.rendered = function (){
 var self = this; 
   Meteor.defer(function() {
    debugger;
    new FastClick(document.body);
    console.log("Template.leaderboard.rendered: " + self );
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bento, that was it.

That should have been obvious (it's in a callback so of course "this" has changed - duh) but I missed it...

Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It happens to the best of us!

Answer (score -1):

> In the body of the callback, this is a template instance object that is unique to this occurrence of the template and persists across re-renderings. Use the created and destroyed callbacks to perform initialization or clean-up on the object.

Source: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

So `this` references the particular instance of your template that you are rendering.

Comment: Hmm, I think you just repeated my original question - I don't see an answer.